# mobile/tablet device orientation partly working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I'm having a problem with my mobile/tablet device orientation.
So i'm trying to show a div when the device is held in landscape, but not when it's held in portrait. It works when i reload the site in portrait and turn it to landscape, but if i refresh in landscape, then the div dosen't show anymore?

my Js.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){
            $('#rotate').css({display: "block"});
        }else{
            $('#rotate').css({display: "none"});
        }
    }
}, false);
```

my Css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
#rotate{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
}
```

}

Hope sombody can help me! Thanks

Comment: why are you using javascript when you could do everything w/ media queries?

Comment: Because the div has to be hidden on desktops, even if the window is resized. that's why i'm detecting if it's a mobile/tablet device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use only JavaScript this solutions seems to be more elegant and works every time the page is refreshed

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rotate(){
    if (screen.width <= 768) { // do this if the screen is under 768px
        if (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) { // landscape mode
            document.getElementById("rotate").style.display='block';
        }
        else { // portrait mode
            document.getElementById("rotate").style.display='none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#rotate{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="rotate"><p>Hello world</p></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = rotate();
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the example to try to be more clear, hope this helps!